# Make a writable dir in php?

Tags: php

```
mkdir('..'.$this->path.$user, 0777);
```

I'm trying to make a dir on my server with write permission so images uploaded can be written to it.

I do the above but when I check the write permission on the folder created it is 755.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 6):

First thought is [`umask`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).

```
$old = umask(0);
mkdir('..' . $this->path . $user, 0777);
umask($old);
```

Also, you could try setting the folder permission after created using [`chmod`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

```
mkdir('..' . $this->path . $user);
chmod('..' . $this->path . $user, 0777);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have three dirs being created, do I need 3x umask or can I just wrap it round the whole block:

Comment: mkdir('..'.$this->path.$user, 0777);
  mkdir('..'.$this->path.$user.'/gallery', 0777);
  mkdir('..'.$this->path.$user.'/thumb', 0777);

Comment: @user1013512, Yes, just like that

Comment: Hmm, just uploaded to the server and permissions are still 755.

Comment: Not even once? Just the way it is? Also, which OS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know, this is the Linux default rights for a dir.

You can change it with `umask`, see http://php.net/umask